# Replacing @selector with direct code

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, selector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I pass a block as a @selector with Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581782/can-i-pass-a-block-as-a-selector-with-objective-c)

I have this code:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But since doSomething contains so little code, I was wondering if it is possible to put the code straight in here rather than making it run doSomething.

I have tried this already:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:^ { /* code here */ } forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But it just gives an error of "sending (void)^(void) to incompatible type SEL".

Is there a way to do this? If so what is the correct syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: How have you even considered that this would work at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, all of your answers use a lot of unnecessary code which is horribly outdated and no longer works.

I found one answer myself though which I adapted and got this:

```
[myButton addTarget:[^{NSLog(@"Pressed the button");} copy] action:@selector(invoke) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Which works fine.

Comment: Wow. This is clever. +1.

Comment: Working for iOS7 but crashing for iOS8