# How to keep a strong reference inside of a block without having a retain cycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, retain

I have a block attached to a button (using this [category](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4582061/766570)):

```
__unsafe_unretained typeof(UIImage) *weakPic = originalPic;
[button addEventHandler:^{
    switch (state) {
    case state1:
        {
           UIViewController *vc = //some VC
           vc.pic = weakPic; // weakPic is nil at this point
                             // putting originalPic here would solve my problem
                             // but then I would have a retain cycle


        }  

    case state2:
        {
          // other stuff
        }
    }

}];
```

the action associated with the button is different depending on the state.

Here is the problem: I [must](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14556706/766570) keep the above `__unsafe_unretained` to avoid having a retain cycle. However, this code is called at a point where `originalPic = nil`.. and so when I assign `weakPic` to `vc.pic` I'm assigning it a nil value. If I replace `weakPic` with just `originalPic`, then it works fine.. (`originalPic` will have the updated value) but then I get the retain cycle.. ideas?

Comment: What makes you think you think you have a dangerous retain cycle?

Comment: If it is guaranteed that the event handler block is always called eventually, then you have a "temporary retain cycle", and you can ignore the warning or suppress it with a compiler pragma.

Comment: Alternatively, if originalPic is a property, then you can get a weak reference to `self` and call `weakSelf.originalPic` within the block, which is how I usually do it.

Comment: @MartinR You understood my point perfectly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about your code I suggest you consider declaring a weakSelf and implementing an accessor on self.

```
//the accessor
-(UIImage*)pic{
    return originalPic;
}

-(void)someSetupMethod{
    __weak id weakSelf = self;

    [button addEventHandler:^{
        switch (state) {
        case state1:
            {
               UIViewController *vc = //some VC
               vc.pic = [weakSelf pic]; // if weakself is nil at this point, then
                                        // originalPic is likely invalid


            }  

        case state2:
            {
              // other stuff
            }
        }

    }];
}
```

It may not be a weakSelf you want, but some other object. In that case just declare that other object to be weak, as long as you can be relatively sure it will exist as long or longer than the button.

Answer (score -1):

You might also want to look at declaring it as a __block variable. The __block keyword prevents a copy of the object from being made inside the block.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773342/what-the-difference-between-weak-and-block-reference) thread for a better explanation of __weak and __block references.

Comment: Under ARC it's no longer the case that a `__block` pointer does not retain: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#id50