# Inline Block/Function with Selector in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there a native language feature for inline selectors in Swift? If not, is there an elegant pattern for this?

For example, an NSTimer using a Selector. This is a way you can do it without any inline function or block:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

@objc func update() {
    print("timer up")
}
```

I would rather have something like this. *This is a concept and does not compile.*

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2,
        target: self,
        selector: { println("timer up") }, // What can I do here?
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: false)
```

This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581782/can-i-pass-a-block-as-a-selector-with-objective-c) asked about inline selectors in Objective C.

Answer (score 3):

This code is bridged to Objective-C, and there's no way to do it there. The string you pass is ultimately converted to a selector (`SEL`) and passed to `objc_msgSend`. So, no.

You could take a look at [BlocksKit](https://github.com/zwaldowski/BlocksKit), which [adds these `NSTimer` methods](https://github.com/zwaldowski/BlocksKit/blob/master/BlocksKit/Core/NSTimer+BlocksKit.h), which would convert to closures in Swift.