# Error sending void(^)(UIButton *_strong) to parameter of incompatible type SEL

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to replace "@selector" with a function block here. But doing this shows an error saying:

**error: sending 'void (^)(UIButton *__strong)' to parameter of incompatible** **type 'SEL'**

Please instruct on how to put a function block directly, instead of using "@selector".

```
[_contactPhoneButton addTarget:self
                        action:^(UIButton *sender) {
  NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:sender.titleLabel.text];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Block can not be converted to SEL.They are different types.

- SEL is a name to identify function,it is send to object.During runtime,the object use SEL to find function to execute
- Block is some code you can execute,it is independent of Object.

If you still want to use block,refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4582061/3940672).

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace a `Selector` with a `Block` as they are different types. You could however look at using something like `ReactiveCocoa` to achieve the kind of approach you are going for.

[Reactive Cocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa)

Answer (score 1):

You must add selector, not block:

```
[_contactPhoneButton addTarget:self
                        action: @selector(buttonTapped:)];
```

and then

```
- (void) buttonTapped: (uibutton*) sender
{
 NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:sender.titleLabel.text];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
 [_contactPhoneButton addTarget:[^{
        NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:sender.titleLabel.text];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
    } copy] action:@selector(invoke) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```